# Confine clipping mask to single layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a clipping mask, but am having difficulties as it seems that the mask is applying to background layers. Here is how things look before I create the mask:

[image]

and here is what things look like after:

[image]

And here's what things look like when I take out the background:

[image]

I'd like to confine my clipping mask to the orange area in the before picture. How do I do this while keeping the orange color and without getting the "sky background" coloring blended into the mask?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be **very** localized and file specific. If this could be edited to be more about theory or practice it may be a better fit for the site.

Comment: The actual details of the question might  be specific, but the principles of illustrator that I'm requesting help with are certainly applicable to other situations. Besides, Stack Exchange is *supposed* to deal with specific questions. If you don't like the question then just don't answer it.

Comment: Help files will teach application basics.

Comment: @Danny Scott is trying to help improve the quality of the question and, correspondingly, the site by guiding through his comment. If you're unwilling to improve your question it may be closed for the reasons he specified

Comment: @MarkMussler, I included specifics in my question because I felt it would be too difficult to describe the general illustrator concept that applies here without them.  If I had written a question saying "How do I make a clipping mask affect only a single layer?" and spoken in generalities, then you guys probably would have voted to close the question for being too broad and vague. I am active on other stack exchange sites, and know how the sites are structured.

Comment: @Scott I looked through the help files and did numerous google searches. I didn't find anything that applied to this situation. If the question is so "basic" then why don't you just answer it instead of voting to close it? Last I heard, stack exchange was supposed to cater to the novice and advanced user alike.

Comment: Yes we are to cater to novice and expert users. But, my personal opinion is, we are not hear to teach users *how* to use applications. This question could not *effectively* be answered without seeing your file and understanding *exactly* how you have things constructed. While seeing the layers panel in the screen shots is *somewhat* helpful, it's not enough. I **did** answer the theory portion of your question. If I feel I need to see your file to effectively answer, then I feel this is just too localized and off topic. I am only 1 opinion though.

Comment: Common sense would say.. if you don't want the blue over the mountains... remove or hide the blue. *How* you do that is a matter of opinion and file dependent. Google does turn up 56,000 results for "How to use clipping masks in Illustrator"

Comment: I think this behavior in Illustrator is confusing enough and so lacking in documentation that it deserves some help from SE. I hope the down votes will be lifted or countered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question is a little file specific, but I'm sure you're not the only one stuck at this basic point ...*

Judging by the screens you provided, it appears that you have a couple of things going on:

- The orange "mountains" consist of a fill and blending mode to create the color overlay on the "lake bed" texture.
- You are trying to take that mountain shape, effects and all, and turn it into a clipping mask on the texture.

**That ain't gonna work.** At least not without some re-configuring. When you turn your lovely orange mountains into a clipping mask, it becomes a mask and nothing more: all attributes are removed.

**There are two solutions:**

1. Turn the mountains into a clipping mask then reapply all the attributes to the mask object (you'll need to enter "isolation mode" via a double-click).
2. Duplicate your mountains to create another object above both previous objects and use that as the clipping mask for the two below. The mountains on top will loose all attributes, but the one below will remain intact.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right. It turns out that I needed to apply the coloring to the clipping mask after I created it. I also had to adjust the opacity of the  texture so that it wasn't blocking out the coloring of the clipping mask.

Comment: That's one of those odd things about Illustrator that just becomes part of the way you think after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Clipping mask shapes should encompass the areas you **want visible**.

From your screen shot, it would appear you need to mask or remove the blue gradient from the areas outside your clipping mask. It is really difficult to understand what you are seeking to accomplish though.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more specific. The <image> object of the Terrain layer is a texture that I'd like to have overlayed on the orange area encompassed by a path. As is, the texture is encroaching on the sky. I'd like to keep the texture within the path. If I remove the blue gradient in the background, then I see that the texture has been applied to the path area, but the orange gradient fill is no longer visible.